# Ignore empty calculation errors originating from empty cells

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make formulas using text entries for multiple rows only if they have entries though. The problem is it errors out if one of the editText boxes is empty.

Is there a way to ignore the errors and carry on with the rest of the script? Doing calculations if the entries exist?
There are a total of 3 columns with 6 rows for entries. Each of the 3 entries per row should be filled, but if an entry isn't, I don't want it to calculate for that row or have the answer come up as 0.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    e11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName3);
    e12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName4);
    e13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName5);
    t11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

    e14 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName6);
    e15 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName8);
    e16 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName7);
    t12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);

 }
  public void CalculateMol(View v) {
    float entry11 = Float.parseFloat((e11.getText().toString()));
    float entry12 = Float.parseFloat((e12.getText().toString()));
    float entry13 = Float.parseFloat((e13.getText().toString()));
    float result8 = (entry11 * entry12 * entry13/1000000);
    t11.setText(String.valueOf(result8+"g"));

    float entry14 = Float.parseFloat((e14.getText().toString()));
    float entry15 = Float.parseFloat((e15.getText().toString()));
    float entry16 = Float.parseFloat((e16.getText().toString()));
    float result12 = (entry14 * entry15 * entry16/1000000);
    t12.setText(String.valueOf(result12+"g"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that your editText values are `Empty` or not before calculation.

So inside your `CalculateMol` Method; first validate your input string using this method:

```
public static boolean isEmptyStr(String Val) {
    if (Val == null || Val.isEmpty() || Val.trim().isEmpty() || Val.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

use above method like this;

```
 public void CalculateMol(View v) {
 float entry11;

 if(!isEmptyStr(e11.getText().toString())){
        entry11 = Float.parseFloat((e11.getText().toString()));
 }
}
```

then apply your calculations.